# django template tag to jquery

Tags: jquery, django, templates, tags

How to run jquery script for iteration result through django template tag that is return as a context from django view ?

e.g.

views:

```
context['substages'] = SubStage.objects.all()
context['trsubstages'] = TRSubStage.objects.all()
```

template:

```
{% for substage in trsubstage.substages_related %}
    <td style="width:40px" align="center">
    <a href="#" id="username{{ substage.id }}" data-type="text" data-placement="right" data-title="Enter username">
    {{ substage.substage_value }}</a></td>
{% endfor %}
```

So my jquery grabs id="username{{ substage.id }}" but I do not know how to use {{ substage.id }} in jquery.

So, at the moment I use this code in my jquery script:

```
$('#username').editable
```

but I would like to use sth like:

```
$('#username{{ substage.id }}').editable
```

but obviously it will not work.

below is my jquery script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //toggle `popup` / `inline` mode
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

$('#username').editable({
    type: 'text',
    title: 'Enter username',
    success: function(response, newValue) {
        userModel.set('username', newValue); //update backbone model
    }
});

    //make status editable
    $('#status').editable({
        type: 'select',
        title: 'Select status',
        placement: 'right',
        value: 2,
        source: [
            {value: 1, text: 'status 1'},
            {value: 2, text: 'status 2'},
            {value: 3, text: 'status 3'}
        ]
        /*
        //uncomment these lines to send data on server
        ,pk: 1
        ,url: '/post'
        */
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, need to make sure that `{{ substage.id }}` is not `null` or `""` by using `console.log("{{ substage.id }}");`

then if it isn't ,try this :

```
var id = "#username"+"{{ substage.id }}";
```

Then you call `id`  instead of '#username{{ substage.id }}';

```
$(id).editable
```

Comment: in which place in my jquery script I should define the var id ? thanks

Comment: from `$('#username{{ substage.id }}').editable` to `$(id).editable`

Comment: yes, but where I should place this: var id = "#username"+"{{ substage.id }}";   ? thanks

Comment: somewhere before you use it, maybe on above line

Comment: I have tried it before I have added comment and it have not worked so this is why I have asked comment. However, thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: did you get any error and do you try to log() it   ?

Comment: no error and no I do not log it because I do not know how.

Comment: console.log("{{ substage.id }}");  use this in script tag , then open inspector and see log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111316/discussion-between-bluedog-and-natsathorn).

Answer (score 0):

The reason why I wanted to my pass template tag to jquery was because I wanted to use unique id.

So,

These are two solutions to have it working with multiple ids:

---

### **ORIGINAL PROBLEM**

**html**

```
<td style="width:40px" align="center">
<a href="#" id="{{ substage }}" data-type="text" data-placement="right" data-title="new value">
{{ substage.substage_value }}</a>
</td>
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //toggle `popup` / `inline` mode
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

$('#username').editable({
    type: 'text',
    title: 'new value',
    success: function(response, newValue) {
        userModel.set('username', newValue);
    }
});

});
```

---

### **SOLUTION 1**

**html**

```
<td style="width:40px" align="center">
<div id="username">
<a href="#" data-type="text" data-placement="right" data-name="subs" data-title="new value">
{{ substage.substage_value }}</a>
</div>
</td>
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //toggle `popup` / `inline` mode
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';

$('#username a').editable({
   url: '/post'
    });
});
```

---

### **SOLUTION 2**

**html**

```
<td style="width:40px" align="center">
<a href="#" class="username" data-type="text" data-placement="right" data-title="new value">
{{ substage.substage_value }}</a>
</td>
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //toggle `popup` / `inline` mode
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

$('.username').editable({
    type: 'text',
    title: 'new value',
    success: function(response, newValue) {
        userModel.set('username', newValue);
    }
});

});
```